# tablesorter pagination make buttons move with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

So I have some problem with the way the pagination buttons remain in the same place(at the bottom) even though there are only 2 entries in the last page

http://srikanthrajan.com/test-table/tablesorter.html

Can I do something about it so that the pagination buttons move on top depending on the number of entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently it is positioned as "absolute" in css, try to change it to relative

instead of top: 280px; position: absolute; 
write these in style:
clear:left; float:left;

and also dont forget to float the table to left as well, hope this helps!